# Mongoose .find() only works with _id, not with other fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Document:

```
[
{_id: 0, symbol: "hi"},
{_id: 1, symbol: "bye"}
]
```

Code:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({});

const x = mongoose.model('test', userSchema, 'test-org');

app.get('/api/content/:id', (req, res) => {
  x.find({'symbol': 'XXX'})
      .then((result)=> {
      res.send(result);
    });
});
```

x.find({_id: 0}) and x.find({"_id": 0})
works perfectly fine and returns

{_id: 0, symbol: "hi"}

while:
x.find({symbol: "hi"}) and x.find({"symbol": "hi"})
returns whole array of document, not filtering symbol.

{_id: 0, symbol: "hi"},
{_id: 1, symbol: "bye"}

What did i do wrong?

Many Thanks

Comment: Should we assume you're actually running `x.find({symbol: "hi"})` and not `x.find(symbol: "hi")` as your question states?

Comment: my bad, yes that is correct. I am running x.find({symbol: "hi"}) but returns whole documents without filtering

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `symbol` to the schema definition

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    symbol: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String
    }
});

const x = mongoose.model('test', userSchema, 'test-org');

app.get('/api/content/:id', (req, res) => {
  x.find({'symbol': 'XXX'})
      .then((result)=> {
      res.send(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding "type: Schema.Types.String" gave me an error while adding "type: String" perfectly

Comment: No problem! Feel free to mark this as the correct solution. I've updated the answer to reflect the right `type`